# Process finished with exit code 103

Tags: python

So I was on pycharm and I made a new file to put some code in, but when I ran the code it said "No Python at 'file_name'" Underneath in the terminal it also said "Process Code finished with exit code 103". Anyone know what that means?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory where you installed python, usually `C:\\pythonX`
and copy everything to `C:\Users\ACCOUNT-NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonX`

Answer (score 1):

It means your Pycharm is trying to access python interpreter but unable to locate it or installation of virtual python interpreter was not completed or installed properly.

**Follow these steps**

1. Download python setup from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Install it at the path **C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310**
3. Come back at Pycharm IDE again and try running the script.
4. You are done.
5. See below and verify your installation.

[image: (check screenshot)]

[image]
[image]